# Div that fills width of screen inside Centered Div

Tags: css

Is this possible?  I have Div2 specifically positioned inside Div1.  The only thing now is I would like Div2 to span the width of the entire screen, instead of just spanning the width of Div1.

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|                       Browser                            |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|           --------------------------------               |
|           |        Div1 (relative)       |               |
|           |                              |               |
|           |                              |               |
|-----------|------------------------------|---------------|
|           |           Div2               |               |
|           |(currently absolute & in Div1)|               |
|-----------|------------------------------|---------------|
|           |                              |               |
|           |                              |               |
|           |                              |               |
|           |                              |               |
|           --------------------------------               |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

This is the CSS I have now:

```
.page{
      height: 300px;
      width: 400px;}

.Div1{
    float:left; 
      left: 50%;
    height:200px; 
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
        background-color: red;
}

.Div2{
    position:absolute; 
    top:21px; 
    width:100%; 
    height:24px;
        background-color: yellow;
}​
```

Here is JSFiddle for my current problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vBqgT/21/
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need CSS3 do accomplish this.  Since `div2` is inside `div1`, it's width is constrained by `div1`.  Therefore, to make `div2` wider than `div1`:

```
.Div2{
    width:150%; 
}
```

You can also do this:

```
.Div2{
    left: -25%;
}
```

to adjust where the left edge of `div2` starts.

See http://jsfiddle.net/jsxvK/.

But if the main goal is for `div2` to take on the properties of the body (`page` in your case), consider putting the markup for `div2` inside `page`, but not inside `div`.  Then adjust the top position of `div2` to move it up or down in the document.

Comment: This way works best on my site.  It hadn't occurred to me to use these percentages.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do that, but the position of div2 is given relative to div1 (thus left:0 whould place it left aligned to div1) if you make div2 a child of div1. If you don't want to place it relative to div1 you can either make div2 a sibling to div1 or you can remove `position: relative;` from div1. Another alternative is to use fixed position on div2. All of these have side effects that may not be desirable...

Sometimes it is necessary to use javascript to get exactly what you want. Say for example that you want to align to div1 on one axis and to the body on the other. Then it may be necessary to use scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
.page{
      height: 300px;
      width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid red;
}

.Div1{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.Div2{
    position:absolute;
    top:21px;
    width:100%;
    height:24px;
    background-color: yellow;
    left:0;
}
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/SqG3c/

Comment: This works great in the demo, but KatieK's worked better when I put it in my own page.  I wish I could have accepted both your answers.